# ¿Qué significa embedded nul(s) found in input en R?

Tags: base-de-datos, r

Hace dias estoy trabajando con los mismos datos, pero por alguna razón la última vez que los bajé, me salió esta advertencia:

> ```
> Warning message:
> In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
> embedded nul(s) found in input
> ```

Para bajar los datos usé:

> ```
> mice<-read.csv("https://github.com/direcciondemiuniversidad/MyData.csv")
> ```

Sustituí con direcciondemiuniversidad la página por privacidad.

El problema es que había funcionado perfecto por semanas, hasta hoy.

Usé `View(mice)` y los datos se ven perfectamente normales, sin celdas vacías o NAs. **¿Cómo lo arreglo?**

Comment: He encontrado este enlace relacionado por ahí, igual te sirve: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23209464/get-embedded-nuls-found-in-input-when-reading-a-csv-using-read-csv)

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre posibles temas a revisar:

- Que no existan campos en blanco
- Todas las líneas deberían tener salto de línea "\n" o "\r\n"
- Revisar que no aparezca el separador usado (por ej. ',' o ';') dentro de alguna de las columnas
- Verificar el "encoding" del archivo y si es necesario importarlo con dicha configuración: `mice<-read.csv("https://github.com/direcciondemiuniversidad/MyData.csv", fileEncoding="UTF-16LE")`
- De última, se podría quitar el "warning" mediante le parámetro `skipNul = TRUE`